# Using Ruby to read json then output back out as json

Tags: ruby, json, http, file-io, cgi

I am trying to read the information I am returning from a local .json file. How do I get ruby to return the json information from this file? What I have so far:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
require 'json'
require 'cgi'

cgi = CGI::new()

if cgi.request_method == 'GET' then
  json = File.read('path/to/file.json')
  print json
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ruby 1.9.3 there is no File.read do this:

```
if cgi.request_method == 'GET'
    print File.open('path/to/file.json').read
end
```

Also you should use http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-i-out

```
cgi.out("nph"        => true,
    "status"     => "OK",  # == "200 OK"
    "server"     => ENV['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],
    "connection" => "close",
    "type"       => "text/html",
    "charset"    => "iso-2022-jp",
      # Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-2022-jp
    "language"   => "ja",
    "expires"    => Time.now + (3600 * 24 * 30),
    "cookie"     => [cookie1, cookie2],
    "my_header1" => "my_value",
    "my_header2" => "my_value") { "string" }
```

Comment: Ruby 1.9.3 has `File.read`. Here's the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-read).